# What causes EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION and how to Solve it?

Tags: java, jna, rcp

I was performing some operation in my RCP Application. All of a sudden, my tool crashed and closed. I got the following error in ***hs_err*** file.
Please help me out with this issue.

```
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000007fefb3a2330, pid=4812, tid=0x0000000000004b18
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_152-b16) (build 1.8.0_152-b16)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.152-b16 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x000007fefb3a2330
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000314df800):  JavaThread "Thread-27" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=19224, stack(0x0000000047b00000,0x0000000047c80000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0xffffffffe1911058
```

Comment: There isn't enough information here to begin to help. Something in the 'native' code is using a bad address.

Comment: You may be passing an invalid pointer somewhere. Some JNA mapping may be wrong. It could be so many things - this is almost like asking "what does a NullPointerException mean and how to solve it" in the Java side. Please find the smallest amount of code you can to reproduce the error, then include that code snippet in your question.